# How could that question could have been improved?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I recently asked a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/112273/how-does-this-artefact-work-in-ww84) about the latest Wonder Woman movie.

I was surprised by the almost equal number of up- and down-votes (currently +4/-3). This suggests something but I am genuinely curious what:

- not enough research? (I did not know about that artefact, the closest I could find was https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Dreamstone - but this does not answer my questions, it is true that I could have added that to the question once I found this reference)
- not interesting enough? (this is subjective and that could be a reason)
- not "movie-ish" enough? (in the sense that I am looking for too much logic and consistency - well, I am not watching the movie as a documentary either :), but still interested in what the writers had in mind)

Comment: I don't know ... seemed fine to me.  Questions about how the logic and consistency of other movies seem on topic.  I don't understand why this one wouldn't be equally on topic and interesting to someone.  Perhaps it doesn't help that the movie was simply awful compared to the original - so people care less about the internal consistency of the main macguffin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it was downvoted, particularly, but the help center says this: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

You actually have five, or six, questions in your question. Turning it into one question is generally seen as a good thing (sometimes an essential thing, depending on where you ask). I don't know if multiple questions are allowed here (I checked and didn't see anything that said they were forbidden; please point me to the right place, if you know where it is), but I know they're not allowed on some popular networks (so if they are allowed here, people coming from other networks may have seen it and downvoted it because of an assumption that they're generally not allowed).

Anyway, if the question could be split up into multiple questions, it's generally advisable to ask every single one of them separately on StackExchange. Alternatively, you can rephrase the things you want to know so it's clear you want to know them without them actually being questions (and just have your main question).

Anyway, it was more common for people to care about this sort of thing a few years ago; I don't know if people just see it as nitpicking now or not.